# How to locate the difference in default NULL and NULL string value

Tags: sql

I have a table for e.g.

```
Merchant(
    id (PK,char(15),not null),
    name (varchar(22),null),
    city(varchar(10),null),
    location(varchar(10),null),
    state_code(int,null),
    country_code(int,null)
)
```

Where `city` is always `NULL` and `name` is also `NULL`.

Someone updated these fields as the *string* `"NULL"`.

How can I find the difference?

Comment: you want to check difference in records'values or in schema ??

Comment: The better way is update your rows with "NULL" for NULL and fix the bug in your code to write NULL correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the problematic rows like so:

```
UPDATE Merchant
SET city = NULL
WHERE city = 'NULL';

UPDATE Merchant
SET name = NULL
WHERE name = 'NULL';
```

---

To simply find the rows with the *string* `"NULL"`:

```
SELECT * FROM Merchant
WHERE city = 'NULL'
OR name = 'NULL';
```

Or to find real `NULL`s:

```
SELECT * FROM Merchant
WHERE city = NULL
OR name = NULL;
```

---

**Notice across all of these examples:** there is `NULL`, and then there is `'NULL'`.

Comment: No, The question is how can i find which NULL value is actually NULL and not 'NULL' string in the table records

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Merchant 
WHERE city = 'NULL'
OR name = 'NULL'
```

This should return all rows where either column city or column name is set to the string NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM Merchant 
WHERE city IS NULL
OR name IS NULL
```

Will return all rows where either column city or column name is *NULL*

Answer (score 0):

- NULL means not set
- An empty string is a string without a sign

It's more simple with numbers for e.g. with a amount to pay (a bill):
 - The amount to pay is 0 (you have nothing to pay) [`amount = 0`]
 - The amount can be 100.- (you have to pay 100.-) [`amount = 100`]
 - or the amount can be NULL, which means the amount has not been set (yet) [`amount is null`]

The statement in brackets will return true for the given case.

So you see, it's not the same an amount of 0 (no money to pay) or NULL (not set). It's the same with your string. It's not been set or is an empty string.

I hope it helps you... ;-)